# Joining two dataframes without a common column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes which has different types of columns. I need to join those two different dataframe. Please refer the below example

```
val df1 has
Customer_name 
Customer_phone
Customer_age

val df2 has
Order_name
Order_ID
```

These two dataframe doesn't have any common column. Number of rows and Number of columns in the two dataframes also differs. I tried to insert a new dummy column to increase the row_index value as below
val dfr=df1.withColumn("row_index",monotonically_increasing_id()).

But as i am using Spark 2, monotonically_increasing_id method is not supported. Is there any way to join two dataframe, so that I can create the value of two dataframe in a single sheet of excel file.

For example

```
val df1:
Customer_name  Customer_phone  Customer_age
karti           9685684551     24      
raja            8595456552     22

val df2:
Order_name Order_ID
watch       1
cattoy     2
```

My final excel sheet should be like this:

```
Customer_name  Customer_phone  Customer_age   Order_name  Order_ID

karti          9685684551      24             watch        1
   
raja           8595456552      22             cattoy      2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`monotonically_increasing_id()` is ***increasing*** and ***unique*** but not ***consecutive***.

You can use `zipWithIndex` by converting to `rdd` and reconstructing Dataframe with the same schema for both `dataframe`.

```
import spark.implicits._


val df1 = Seq(
  ("karti", "9685684551", 24),
  ("raja", "8595456552", 22)
).toDF("Customer_name", "Customer_phone", "Customer_age")


val df2 = Seq(
  ("watch", 1),
  ("cattoy", 2)
).toDF("Order_name", "Order_ID")

val df11 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  df1.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
  },
  // Create schema for index column
  StructType(df1.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
)


val df22 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  df2.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
  },
  // Create schema for index column
  StructType(df2.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
)
```

Now join the final dataframes

```
df11.join(df22, Seq("index")).drop("index")
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+--------+
|Customer_name|Customer_phone|Customer_age|Order_name|Order_ID|
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+--------+
|karti        |9685684551    |24          |watch     |1       |
|raja         |8595456552    |22          |cattoy    |2       |
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: that's a bit convoluted and lengthy TBH. @ss301's answer is simpler.

Answer (score 9):

add an index column to both dataframe using the below code

```
df1.withColumn("id1",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df2.withColumn("id2",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

then join both the dataframes using the below code and drop the index column

```
df1.join(df2,col("id1")===col("id2"),"inner")
   .drop("id1","id2")
```

Comment: I would suggest using monotonically_increasing_id since monotonicallyIncreasingId is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I'm on Databricks, so I used Python/PySpark.
In case anyone has the same question in a Python environment, this did the trick for me:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, row_number


w = Window().orderBy(lit(None))
df1 = df1.withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(w))
df2 = df2.withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(w))

df_merged = df1.join(df2, 'row_num').drop('row_num')
```