# merge dataframes with no attributes in common

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to merge dataframes from DF1 and DF2 , in order to get a DF3=[DF1,DF2] . where DF3 must be with two columns, col1=[site] and col2=Date
what's the best way to do so in pyspark ? thanks in advance

§ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrGHS.png)
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlMBW.png)
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738694/join-two-dataframe-without-having-common-column-spark-scala

Comment: Does it have same number of rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join two dataframe without having common column spark, scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738694/join-two-dataframe-without-having-common-column-spark-scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use monotonically increasing ID if you have the same number of rows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df1.withColumn("id_col", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df2 = df2.withColumn("id_col", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

df3 = df1.join(df2, on="id_col", how="inner")
# You can drop the id_col column after this
df3 = df3.drop("id_col")
```

This is the easiest way to do it

Comment: This will not always work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738694/join-two-dataframe-without-having-common-column-spark-scala

Comment: it says : AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'monotonicallyIncreasingId'

Comment: `monotonically_increasing_id`

Comment: thanks @Bala , works as magic !

Comment: @HoussemBZYWISH Please select and upvote if helped

Comment: @pissall I just created a new account (use it for company work) , so stackoverflow says i cant vote due to some new reputation stuff , i wish i could vote

Comment: @HoussemBZYWISH Just select the tick-mark to select the answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

neither of the proposed answers above solves the question . 
here is one eficient way to solve it :

## SINCE  monotonically_increasing_id, which is by definition non-deterministic. I DID THE FOLLOWING :

convert to RDD
 zipWithIndex
convert back to DataFrame.
join
this solves the question pretty easily