# How to add a list or array of strings as a column to a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So, I have `n` number of strings that I can keep either in an array or in a list like this:

```
val checks = Array("check1", "check2", "check3", "check4", "check5")
val checks: List[String] = List("check1", "check2", "check3", "check4", "check5")
```

Now, I have a spark dataframe `df` and I want to add a column with the values present in this List/Array. (It is guaranteed that the number of items in my List/Array will be exactly equal to the number of rows in the dataframe, i.e `n`)

I tried doing:
`df.withColumn("Value", checks)`
But that didn't work. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: create dataframe from `checks` list then [join by adding a common index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738694/joining-two-dataframes-without-a-common-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it as an array column as follows:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Value", array(checks.map(lit):_*))
```

If you want a single value for each row, you can get the array element:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Value", array(checks.map(lit):_*))
            .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1))) - 1)
            .withColumn("Value", expr("Value[rn]"))
            .drop("rn")
```