# Is there any wrong when a dataframe join an another dataframe with a column using monotonically_increasing_id?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For an example,I have two dataframe such like this.

a:

```
name|age   
Ted |15
```

b:

```
name|weight  
Ted |75
```

And I use `a.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id)` to generate a unique column for dataframe `a`. Then I save dataframe `a`.

When I use `b.join(a,"name")`, it is possible to get the wrong id not same as dataframe `a`.

It doesn't happen steadily. And I found that the error ids are in the same number range.T he first few digits of the number are the same. It looks like a certain range of ids got confused. I have to use `zipwithIndex` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining two dataframes without a common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738694/joining-two-dataframes-without-a-common-column)

Comment: Not exactly consistent.My dataframe have a same column,and I want to join them with it.